# Hide and show textarea in odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo

I have some questions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
  <template id="product_configurator_configure" 
    inherit_id="sale.product_configurator_configure">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='js_product main_product']" 
      position="replace">
      some code
    <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="check_comment" class="o_website_form_input"> Option development 
          request</input>
       <textarea name="comment"  id="comment" class="o_website_form_input" cols="65" rows="4" 
          placeholder="Add new option"></textarea>
    </div>
  </xpath>
 </template>
```

How to create a javascript file (its structure) in odoo so that by clicking on the "checkbox" the field <textarea name = "comment" appears. How to connect a file to a template, what structure should it have, and how to set up an event listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [alter](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/web.html#modify-existing-widgets-and-classes) the [ProductConfiguratorFormRenderer](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale/static/src/js/product_configurator_renderer.js#L7) renderer and bind the click [event](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/web.html#events) to the comment checkbox.

```js
odoo.define('web.CustomFormRenderer', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var ProductConfiguratorFormRenderer = require('sale.ProductConfiguratorFormRenderer');

    ProductConfiguratorFormRenderer.include({

        events: _.extend({}, ProductConfiguratorFormRenderer.prototype.events, {
            'click #check_comment': 'onClickShowHideComment',
        }),

        onClickShowHideComment: function (ev) {
            let comment = $(ev.currentTarget).next();
            if(ev.currentTarget.checked) {
                comment.removeClass('o_hidden');
            } else {
                comment.addClass('o_hidden');
            }
        },
    });

});
```

To add the above code, check the [Assets Management](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#assets-management) documentation.

***Example:***

- Create a js file (`custom_form_renderer.js`) with the above code.
- Inherit `web.assets_backend` and include the js file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="Custom assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/{module_name}/static/src/js/custom_form_renderer.js"></script>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

- Add the xml file to the manifet.